# Notification about linking questions and answers

Tags: feature-request, notifications

I think it would be nice to have notifications in inbox that someone linked to my question or answer. So when, for example, someone links to my question (or answer) in his/her comment or post, I would be notified about this.

I see at least two advantages of it:

- it would help to keep track how our posts "live" here and how often they are used,
- it would allow to make some additional comments and take part of the discussion

I see only one probable disadvantage - it can produce tons of messages for more experienced users.